# Java - JPanel - painting contents of a text file with an arraylist - Only works the first time

Tags: java, swing, command-prompt, paintcomponent, notepad

I have a program with a JMenuBar. Inside the JMenuBar has a JButton, the JButton opens up a JMenu that has 2 JMenuItems. When you click on one of the items, it opens a second JFrame, and prints the contents of a text file line by line.

If you select the other option (in the same session), it should change the JFrame title (this works), and print the contents of the other text file (this doesn't work).

I've pinpointed what the issue is, but I have no clue on why this issue is occurring. What's occurring is the code works perfectly the first time it displays the contents of the text file. However, the second time it does not change the text.

What I've found during the second time is described in the comments. Start at the setDocument method, and then move to the paintComponent method.

Here is the class with the issue (there are several other classes for the program, but the issue is solely within this class)...

```
package PeriodicTable;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.lang.Override;

class DocumentPanel extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<String> aryDocument;
DocumentPanel(){
    super();
    setBackground(Color.white);
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    //aryDocument holds the contents of the old text file (should have the contents of the other text file)
    for(int index = 0; index < aryDocument.size(); index++){
        //enters loop, re-prints the old document
        gr.drawString(aryDocument.get(index), 5, (index + 1)*10);
    }
}
public void setDocument(String strFileDirectory){ //places contents of text file in an array (line by line)

    //aryDocument is null at this time
    aryDocument = new ArrayList<String>();
    //aryDocument is empty at this time
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFileDirectory))){
        for(String strLine; (strLine = reader.readLine()) != null; ){
            aryDocument.add(strLine);
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    //aryDocument holds the contents of the other text file
    this.revalidate();
}
}
```

The following method is in a class called Table (Table implements ActionListener). This method is called by actionPerformed, who uses the ActionCommand value to determine what action does what.

```
private void loadTextFile(String strName, String strFileDirectory){
    DocumentPanel clsDocumentPanel = new DocumentPanel();
    if(frmDocument == null){
        frmDocument = new JFrame(strName);
        frmDocument.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 700));
        clsDocumentPanel.setDocument(strFileDirectory);
        frmDocument.add(clsDocumentPanel);
        frmDocument.pack();
        frmDocument.setVisible(true);
    }else{
        if(!(frmDocument.getTitle().equals(strName))){
            frmDocument.setTitle(strName);
            clsDocumentPanel.setDocument(strFileDirectory);
            frmDocument.pack();
            frmDocument.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I've rechecked strFileDirectory and confirmed they are the correct values.

What versions/programs/etc am I using?

Java 8

Notepad

Command Prompt

My question in clearly stated...

Why isn't aryDocument's value changing when it goes into paintComponent (after loading the other text file)? How can I fix it?

Comment: Who (what thread) calls `setDocument`?

Comment: The default thread system, I have not done anything using threads with this program. As for the path that leads to setDocument, when you click on the JMenuItem, an actionPerformed method sorts out ActionCommands to determine what to do. This is done in a different class.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you call `setDocument`, *then* `paintComponent` is called and it has the old value of `setDocument`, everything in a single thread?

Comment: It should be, I don't have that much experience with threads. Since the java docs say swing is not thread-safe, I didn't try to work with it. If it is needed, then I guess I'll have to learn to make safe threads with swing.

Comment: In Swing, everything should happen in one thread unless you create more explicitly. OK, I don't get another thing: you say that `aryDocument` is `null` in `setDocument`, but then it suddenly contains old file. Why is it `null`? You don't ever set it to `null`. It's only `null` when you create the frame, but once you populate it with the contents of the first file, it can't possibly become `null` again. Doesn't make sense. How did you figure out the facts that you're stating in the comments?

Comment: I suppose an alternative could be to have a method that holds arraylist<string> literals, though I think having text files, and reading the text files line by line would be better...

Comment: Could it be that you're dealing with several instances of the frame, only one of which is visible?

Comment: well, aryDocument starts as a un-initialized global variable. To test what value it holds on the second time that setDocument is called, I put a bunch of System.out.println through out certain points in the code. The first was before aryDocument is initialized in setDocument, the second is after it is intialized in setDocumet, and the third is before the revalidate method is called. After that, there was a fourth before the for-loop in paintComponent. I just had a thought, what if aryDocument is initialized in the class constructor, and I empty it at the start of setDocument...

Comment: Currently at any given time 1 JFrame is open, when a JMenuItem is clicked, a second JFrame is opened, if that second one is not already open.

Comment: That thought I had didn't work. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Thankfully, it's *not* global (global variables are a nightmare). It's an instance variable. And you're saying there are two frames? Please edit the question to clarify the order in which things happen: frame creation, `setDocument` calls, `setVisible` calls and so on. As it stands, it's impossible to answer. Please also clarify what you're trying to achieve: change the text in an existing frame or open another frame with another text?

Comment: I'll add the creation of the second JFrame immediately following the posted code.

Comment: Please also add those `println`s into the code and their output.

Comment: Will do this, I just finished adding the code for the second JFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here,

```
DocumentPanel clsDocumentPanel = new DocumentPanel(); // <- yes, here!
if(frmDocument == null){
    frmDocument = new JFrame(strName);
    frmDocument.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 700));
    clsDocumentPanel.setDocument(strFileDirectory);
    frmDocument.add(clsDocumentPanel);
    frmDocument.pack();
    frmDocument.setVisible(true);
}else{
    if(!(frmDocument.getTitle().equals(strName))){
        frmDocument.setTitle(strName);
        clsDocumentPanel.setDocument(strFileDirectory);
        frmDocument.pack();
        frmDocument.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

you create a new instance of `DocumentPanel` each time the action is performed. The first time you add it to `frmDocument`. The second time you just call `setDocument` on it and let it be garbage collected. The first instance (actually attached to the displayed frame) is never updated.

So, either

- store `clsDocumentPanel` somewhere separately, just like you store `frmDocument`, *not* as a local variable;
- make `frmDocument` a `JFrame` subclass that exposes access to its document panel and call `frmDocument.getDocumentPanel().setDocument(...)`—but this violates Demeter's Law;
- or make `frmDocument` a `JFrame` subclass that has a `setDocument` method that just delegates to `setDocument` of its panel, then just call `frmDocument.setDocument(...)`.

Comment: I moved the DocumentPanel reference creation outside of the method, and the creation of the instance into Table's constructor, however the problem is still occurring. I'll continue getting this System.outs and the command results in the OP.

Comment: Cancel that last comment, an edit I did earlier interfered with the fix. After undoing that edit, It is working fine now. Thanks for the help!